# Django Rest Framework refers to default database for checking relationship constraints (for eg. foreign key)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for creating the CRUD APIs and have to deal with multiple databases (having same schema) depending on the request.

models.py

```
class CustomerMaster(models.Model):
    customer_key = models.IntegerField(db_column='CUSTOMER_KEY', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    first_name = models.TextField(db_column='FIRST_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    last_name = models.TextField(db_column='LAST_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gender = models.TextField(db_column='GENDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dob = models.DateField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone = models.CharField(db_column='PHONE', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address = models.TextField(db_column='ADDRESS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
  ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer_master'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sib_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Segment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    selection = JSONField()
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contact = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerMaster)
    sib_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class SegmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=CustomerMaster.objects.all(), slug_field='email')
    createdBy = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'folder', 'selection', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy', 'contact', 'sib_id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        club = self.context['club']
        contact_data = validated_data.pop('contact')
        segment = Segment.objects.using(club).create(**validated_data)
        segment.contact.add(*contact_data)
        return segment

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        club = self.context['club']
        instance.contact.clear()
        contact_data = validated_data.pop('contact')
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.folder = validated_data.get('folder', instance.folder)
        instance.selection = validated_data.get('selection', instance.selection)
        instance.save(using=club)
        instance.contact.add(*contact_data)
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class SegmentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SegmentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        club = self.kwargs['club']
        return Segment.objects.using(club).all()

    def post(self, request, club, format=None):
        serializer = SegmentSerializer(data=request.data, context={'club': club})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            folder = get_object_or_404(Folder.objects.using(club).all(), pk=int(request.data["folder"]))
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here in my Segment model, folder is a foreign key referencing to Folder model. I need to use the database based on the request url and all the databases have same schemas. The GET request works fine. However, for the POST and PUT requests, DRF checks the foreign key constraint of folder in the default database.
For example
POST Request:

```
{
        "name": "Testing",
        "folder": 8,
        "selection": "{'testing': 20}",
        "contact": []
}
```

It is giving me the following response:

```
{
    "folder": [
        "Invalid pk \"8\" - object does not exist."
    ]
}
```

But the folder with pk "8" exists in the intended database.

I am using python 3.7, django 2.2.11, django rest framework 3.11.0

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is_valid() always uses 'default' db it seems, however you can override your fields to use the desired database in serializer init method. Worked for me.